# python recursive function returning none instead of string

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

The below python function prints value using print function but is returning none if made to return string value. can anyone help me on how to return a string value from this below function.

```
csv_full_list = ['mycsv_0', 'mycsv_1']


def create_csv_name(comm, index):
    global csv_full_list
    if comm + '_' + str(index) in csv_full_list:
        index += 1 # increment index by 1
        create_csv_name(comm, index=index)
    else:
        print '%s_%i' % (comm, index)
        return '%s_%i' % (comm, index)


print(create_csv_name('mycsv', 0))
```

out put expected :

> mycsv_2

but returns:

> None

Comment: You don't return from the `if`

Comment: how does it prints value inside function then?

Comment: You should return from the recursive call: `return create_csv_name(comm, index=index)`

Comment: can you elaborate. I tried but getting error: **RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following code.

```
csv_full_list = ['mycsv_0', 'mycsv_1']


def create_csv_name(comm, index):
    global csv_full_list
    result = True
    print "ATTEMPT: COMM: {}, INDEX: {}".format(comm, index)

    while result:
        if comm + '_' + str(index) not in csv_full_list:
            result = False

        else:
            index += 1 # increment index by 1
            #print "--> Found COMM: {}, INDEX: {}".format(comm, index)
            create_csv_name(comm, index=index)

    if not result:
        return "\n\nStopping at >> COMM: {}, INDEX: {}".format(comm, index)

# Call the def
print(create_csv_name('mycsv', 0))
```

2nd variation:

```
csv_full_list = ['mycsv_0', 'mycsv_1']


def create_csv_name(comm, index):
    global csv_full_list
    result = True
    print "ATTEMPT: COMM: {}, INDEX: {}".format(comm, index)

    if comm + '_' + str(index) not in csv_full_list:
        return "\n\nStopping at >> COMM: {}, INDEX: {}".format(comm, index)
    else:
        index += 1 # increment index by 1
        return create_csv_name(comm, index=index)

print(create_csv_name('mycsv', 0))
```

output:

```
> python.exe .\sample.py
ATTEMPT: COMM: mycsv, INDEX: 0
ATTEMPT: COMM: mycsv, INDEX: 1
ATTEMPT: COMM: mycsv, INDEX: 2
ATTEMPT: COMM: mycsv, INDEX: 2


Stopping at >> COMM: mycsv, INDEX: 2
```

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't see why you need the while loop. It's an overkill to achieve the result.

Comment: @nightgaunt agreed, but wanted to keep it simple, so it could be understood easily. As pointed out by your comment the best practice would be to go for `return create_csv_name(comm, index=index)`, Updated the code block. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return create_csv_name(comm, index=index)` inside the function. Otherwise, you are not returning anything from the first call to the function. That also explains your `None` return value.

Recursion is a topic that requires keen observation. And takes some time to get familiar and apply in real application.